# How do I set up HttpSecurity between WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

Both `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` define `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method. However, they don't seem to operate the same way. For example, when I use the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, I don't have to define an `AuthenticationProvider` for `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`, unlike when I use the one in `ResourceConfigurerAdapter`. For this reason, I prefer to use the `configure` method in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, however, having both configurers in my setup causes an exception that says that some bean has already been built (I think it's `springSecurityFilter`). How do I resolve this conflict?